# How to save data into an XML file

Tags: iphone, ios, xml

My application contains 8 TextFields. When I click the submit button I want to save all the values from the TextFields into an XML file (and generate a XML file if required). How can I do this?

Comment: I'd use JSON instead. Unless ofcourse you absolutely have to use XML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways you could do this. One quick and dirty way of doing it is to generate a string in your code and insert the values

e.g.

```
NSString *myXML = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<myxml><value1>%@</value1><value2>%@</value2></myxml>", textfield1, textfield2];
```

Then open a file and write myXML to it.

Not very elegant, but it depends on what exactly you want.

Comment: This response needs to be enhanced with xml escaping, or the output XML will potentially be invalid.

Comment: It was just a very quick and dirty example, not meant to be written and used in production code without testing!

Answer (score 1):

Another XML writer which will get the job done is [XSWI](https://github.com/skjolber/xswi) (shameless plug - I wrote that code).

Answer (score 0):

Do you need the XML file to be in a specific format? If not the easiest way is to save it as a plist (a type of xml file) by putting your strings into an array and then saving the array as a plist using

```
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:label1.text, label2.text, label3.text, etc, nil];
[array writeToFile:fileName atomically:YES];
```

The nice thing about the plist is that you can easily load the string again by calling:

```
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:filename];
```

If you need your XML in a different format from what the plist produces, the easiest way is probably just to build the XML yourself using string concatenation, e.g.

```
NSString *xml = [NSSString stringWithFormat:@"<root><label>%@</label><label>%@</label><label>%@</label>etc</root>", label1.text, label2.text, label3.text, etc];
```

Comment: I would prefer xml, because i might post this xml to the server

Answer (score 0):

You can use GDATAXML to read and write XML to file. 
Refer this link to see how its done.
http://www.raywenderlich.com/725/how-to-read-and-write-xml-documents-with-gdataxml